# Liquibase coming with Spring Boot handles the database well with changelog.xml. How can it generate its sql at the same time?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using the default *Liquibase* configuration coming with *Spring Boot*.

I have:

- a `changelog.xml` file in `src/main/resources/db/changelog` that works fine,
- along with `url`, `changeLogFile`, `driver`, `username`, `password` properties in `application.properties`,
- and a *Maven* `pom.xml` having this for `<dependency>` and `<dependencyManagement>`:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>true</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                        <propertyFile>${project.basedir}/../ApplicationMetierEtGestion/src/main/resources/application.properties</propertyFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Aside from the update of the database structure led by `changelog.xml` that is working fine at development time, I would like *Liquibase* to generate **also** the related *SQL* files (by the mean of its updateSQL command).
This, because the next environments might not have *Liquibase* to handle the database updates.

How can I do that from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase has a goal that generates this SQL for you which is called updateSQL.
Have a look as it might be interesting in your case. 
https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-updatesql.html

Comment: I know this, but how to make it run from Maven spring-boot plugin, if possible, to take advantage of the configuration that is already sat in `application.properties` and `src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog.xml` ?